# "Cannot read property '_view' of null" error when interrupting angular animation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-animations

I have a page with multiple answers where a user can click on one to choose the correct one. When a choice is made, an animation fires showing the user whether they chose correctly. When a user is done, they hit the 'next' button to move on to the next question.

The problem is when a user hits next before the icon animation finishes. When I let the animation run to the end, I do not get the error message.

This is for an ionic application:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 (/Users/rpatulski/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (13 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (/Users/rpatulski/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

With the following angular versions:

```
@angular/core@4.1.3
@angular/animations@4.1.3
```

The answers are drawn in a for loop in the ExamDetailsPage.html template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let curAnswer of question.possibleAnswers">
    <ion-item [ngClass]="getRowAnswerClass(curAnswer)" id={{curAnswer.rowId}} *ngIf="curAnswer.rowId && curAnswer.rowId !==''" (click)="clickedRow(curAnswer)">
        <h5 item-title>{{curAnswer.Text}}</h5>
        <ion-icon [@iconAnimationTrigger]="iconAnimationState" (@iconAnimationTrigger.done)="answerChosenFinished($event)" invalid-icon icon-medium item-right name="close-circle">
        </ion-icon>
        <ion-icon [@iconAnimationTrigger]="iconAnimationState" (@iconAnimationTrigger.done)="answerChosenFinished($event)" correct-icon icon-medium item-right name="checkmark-circle">
        </ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

notice that question.possibleAnswers is the data from the component.

When a user hits the next button the following function runs:

```
showQuestion(){
    ...
    this.indexQ++;
    // the following changes the data needed in the template
    this.question = this.questionArray[this.indexQ - 1];
    ...
}
```

Without interrupting the animation by hitting the 'next' button, I get no error message, otherwise, I get a feeling something is going wrong with change detection. This is the stack trace:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_view' of null
    at ViewContainerRef_.move (core.es5.js:10136)
    at common.es5.js:1722
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.forEachOperation (core.es5.js:7021)
    at NgForOf._applyChanges (common.es5.js:1711)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.es5.js:1701)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10818)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12238)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12177)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12880)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12821)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by not manually calling detectChanges which was missing from my original post:

```
answerChosenFinished(event: AnimationEvent) {
    this.iconAnimationState = IDLE_ANIM_STATE;
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // removed this
}
```